# Beautiful Soup extract tag attributes, then find_all with multiple attributes

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the same information which appears numerous times on the same page.  I am able to find the tag that it fits in which looks like this:

```
<div class="title" style="visibility: visible">
```

From this, i'd like to extract:

```
 class="title"
```

AND

```
style="visibility: visible"
```

Then do a:

```
find_all('div),{'class':'title,'style''visibility: visible'}
```

This is going to happen in numerous instances, so I can't hardcode it.  Sometimes the tag will have a class, sometimes a class and style....sometimes more....

Is this possible?

Really appreciate any direction on this.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> Also, you can use `find_all` method if you want more than one `div` in the content

---

#### code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
data = """<div class="title" style="visibility: visible"> </div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser') #parse content to BeautifulSoup Module
div_content = dict(soup.find("div").attrs)
print("div_content   :  {0}".format(div_content)) #div content
print("style_content :  {0}".format(div_content.get("style"))) # style attribute
print("class_content :  {0}".format(div_content.get("class")[0])) # class attribute
```

---

## output:

```
div_content   :  {u'style': u'visibility: visible', u'class': [u'title']}
style_content :  visibility: visible
class_content :  title
```